# How to convert milliseconds into days?

Tags: java

I need number of days from milliseconds.

I am doing as,

```
long days = (millis / (60*60*24*1000)) % 365;
```

Is this true? If no please tell me how get number of days from milliseconds.

Please **don't suggest** to do

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(millis);
int mDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
long days = (millis / (60*60*24*1000))
```

Answer (score 56):

```
int days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(miliseconds);
```

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure that's correct, but without the modulo.

% 365 means divide it by 365 and get the remainder.

There are (60*60*24*1000) millisecond in a day.

So for conversion:

```
millis/(60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours * 1000 ms/second)
```

should do it.

Answer (score -1):

One that works perfectly fine, but do check the server's standard time. Millisecond in general creates issue or rather mismatch when server's standard time is not what you expect it to be. Code:

```
public boolean isAdult(Date userDob, int minimumAge) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        long dayNow = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(cal.getTimeInMillis());
        cal.setTime(userDob);
        long dayDob = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(cal.getTimeInMillis());
        long ageInDays = dayNow - dayDob;
        long ageInYears = ageInDays / 365;
        if (ageInYears < minimumAge) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```